# How can I change the opacity of a pasted gif in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I have two gifs. I'd like to put one gif on top of the other, but with low opacity.
This is what I did:

1. open gif1.
2. create a new layer
3. paste gif2 onto the layer
4. change the opacity of the layer

The problem is that for all opacity levels above 50%, the image is fully opaque, and for all levels below 50% it disappears.

How can I get the desired effect?

Comment: Try converting the gif to a png first.

Comment: @luckycypher: If that helps, it'll only be by accident (because the indexed-color GIF got converted into an RGBA PNG).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to change the document from indexed color (gif) to RGB (png or jpeg) to make this work. The simpler way to tackle this is to create a fresh RGB document first, then import the gifs.

To import multiple images into the freshly created RGB document, you can use File -> Open As Layers

Comment: thanks for the answer.  the mode is easily changed by going to image -> mode -> RGB.

Comment: Makes sense, since that's how Photoshop works, too. I've never used gimp, but I expect that if you create a blank RGB document first, anything you import would be converted to that color space automatically on import, avoiding the need to make the change manually. I'm all for doing stuff the easy way! :-)